# Destructuring props assignment

Tags: reactjs, destructuring

I'm having some issues with eslint in react. Its asking me to use destructuring props assignment but when I change my code, it breaks.

Any ideas?

This is the full code

```
class LoginPage extends React.Component {
  submit = data =>

    // This is how I tried to fix it!
    // {
    //   const { login, history } = this.props;
    //   login(data).then(() => history.push('/'));
    // };

    // This is what I have, its working but eslint is complaining.
    this.props.login(data).then(() => this.props.history.push('/'));

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Login Page</h1>
            <LoginForm submit={this.submit} />
        </div>
    );
  }
}

LoginPage.propTypes = {
  history: PropTypes.shape({
    push: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }).isRequired,
  login: PropTypes.func.isRequired /* eslint-disable-line */
};

export default connect(
  null,
  { login }
)(LoginPage);
```

The error I get with the modified code is:

```
TypeError: Object(...)(...).then is not a function 
LoginPage._this.submit
src/ components/pages/LoginPage.js:10

7 | class LoginPage extends React.Component {
8 |     submit = data => {
9 |         const { login, history } = this.props;
10 |        login(data).then(() => history.push('/'));
11 |    };
12 | 
13 |    render() {
```

It says the problem is in line 10.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

When you have multiple expression within a function, you need to write it within `{}`. In your case you would write

```
submit = data => {

    const { login, history } = this.props;
    login(data).then(() => history.push('/'));

}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to add that to the code. I used curly braces in my solution at first.

Answer (score 1):

Your fix looks fine, have you tried putting `submit = (data) => { ... }` in curly braces? Unless you're using something like coffeescript, multiple statements (one destructuring assignment and then the call) need to be in a block. That might be why eslint complains but it's working otherwise - it's just one expression, so no block necessary.

Answer (score 1):

As the other point out you need curly braces `{}`. Like the following:

```
submit = data => {

    const { login, history } = this.props;
    login(data).then(() => history.push('/'));

}
```

`es6` arrow function works with the following rules:

- If the after the function there is an expression on the same line it will return it.
- With one argument the parentheses can be ommitted
- When you are writing multiple lines you need to put on `{}` and explicitly return it using a `return` statement.